# How to use auth::attempt() for password that has stored using different encryption technique in laravel5

Tags: laravel, hash

Can I use auth::attempt() function for password that is stored in database table by using password_hash() technique?

I have stored my password using

```
password_hash($myPass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

I want to use

```
auth()->attempt()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Internally, Hash::make() encrypts using the bcrypt function and Blowfish algorithm. For php>5.5, password_hash() and password_verify() functions are used. So you might have luck. why don't you try implementing it

Comment: Tnks @Spanesh Naik.Can you please explain it a little bit with code??Would be highly grateful.:) :)

Answer (score 1):

I think @Spanesh Naik is saying you may not have to do anything because Laravel is using the same function for it's own hashing.

However, to answer in a more general sense for when you really do want a different hash algorithm (for example, I had a site that needed PBKDF2), it's fairly easy to replace or extend Laravel's hasher with your own.

First you need a class to implement your custom hasher:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher as HasherContract;

class MyHasher implements HasherContract
{
   public function make($value, array $options = array())
   {
     // make a new hash here
   }

   public function check($value, $hashedValue, array $options = array())
   {
     // check an existing hash here
   }

   public function needsRehash($hashedValue, array $options = array())
   {
     // return boolean indicating if the hash is using an old algorithm/settings
   }
}
```

Then a service provider to register it:

```
class MyHashServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider 
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('hash', function () {
            return new MyHasher;
        });
    }
}
```

Finally, in your config/app.php in the 'providers' array, comment out the line for

```
Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class
```

and add your own provider

```
Some\Namespace\You\Used\MyHashServiceProvider::class;
```

Comment: tnks a lot for your concern @barryp :) :)